# Rails pass the `id` to the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a model `Item` and standard controller for reviewing items, with `index` & `show` actions. I want to fill `id` in the input field, and get to the `show` route with the id I passed to.

Here is the code:

```
= form_tag items_path, method: :get, enforce_utf8: false do
  = text_field_tag :id, nil, class: 'item_search_field form-control'
  = submit_tag t('.submit'), name: nil, class: 'btn btn-success'
```

But after I pass `id`, saying `55`, I go to the `items#index` with id as param:

http://localhost:3000/items/?id=55

What should I do to be at `localhost:3000/items/55` when I fill the code to `id` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect in index:

```
def index
  if params[:id]
    redirect_to item_path(params[:id]) and return
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do isn't possible with server-side code alone: you'll need to use javascript to take the user's input and build the correct URL. Forms with the GET method append query string parameters, which is what you're seeing, and there's no way to change that without javascript.

Comment: Jon, how can you pass the correct URL with js to the rails form_for?